# Newbie help - Java currency calculator

Tags: java

Im totally new to java and my first task is to make a currency calculator from US dollar to NOK(Norsk Kroner). And the program should calculate and show how this amount most effectively can be cashed out i all norwegian paying units. I Have been trying all day, but getting nowhere. Anybody who can help me out with my code?

Heres my code:

```
/*
 * Valutacalc
 *
 */

import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

public class Kalkulator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Leser verdi fra brukeren
        String tallTxt = showInputDialog("Antall US Dollar");
        int dollar = parseInt(tallTxt);
        double valuta = 5,49;
        // Beregner svarene av regnearbeidet /
        int svar1 = dollar * valuta;
        //Skriv ut resultat
        showMessageDialog(null,   dollar  * " * " valuta " = " + svar1 + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain use you exact problem? What did you try? Does it compile? Etc.

Comment: Not it compiles, and the code calculates right only problem is the shoemessagedialog at the end. The program should calculate and show how this amount most effectively can be cashed out i all norwegian paying units. 1000kr, 500kr,200kr,100kr,50kr,20kr,10kr,5kr,1kr. And i dont have noe idea how i can do this:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
double valuta = 5,49;
```

by

```
double valuta = 5.49;
```

Because decimal point in java is '.' not ','.

May be you also want to change type of `svar1` to `double`

also change:

```
    showMessageDialog(null,   dollar  * " * " valuta " = " + svar1 + "\n");
```

to

```
    showMessageDialog(null,   dollar  + " * " + valuta + " = " + svar1 + "\n");
```

The hole code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Leser verdi fra brukeren
    String tallTxt = showInputDialog("Antall US Dollar");
    int dollar = parseInt(tallTxt);
    double valuta = 5.49;
    // Beregner svarene av regnearbeidet /
    double svar1 = dollar * valuta;   
    //Skriv ut resultat
    showMessageDialog(null,   dollar  + " * " + valuta + " = " + svar1 + "\n");
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it would be better to explain the problems using `double` for these operations.

Comment: Still not working at all, i also have a .class file but i dont understand what that is. Do i have to edit the .class file to make it work?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: It will also work with `int svar1 = ..` (`dollar * valuta` would still be a double multiplication only the result would be cut to `int`), but he might find some decimal places useful.

Comment: C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Skole\Java\Oblig1\Kalkulator.java:17: error: not a statement
    int double = dollar * valuta;

Comment: double svar1 = dollar * valuta;

Comment: C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Skole\Java\Oblig1\Kalkulator.java:19: error: ')' expected
    showMessageDialog(null,   dollar  * " * " valuta " = " = svar1
                                             ^
C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Skole\Java\Oblig1\Kalkulator.java:19: error: ';' expected
    showMessageDialog(null,   dollar  * " * " valuta " = " = svar1
                                                                  ^
2 errors

Comment: I dont understand what line you want me to change, could you post the whole code with your edits?

Comment: Thank you so much, the calculator works now. Just one last problem: the program should calculate and show how this amount most effectively can be cashed out i all norwegian paying units. Anybody know how i can do this?

Comment: Start with the highest unit and use as much of it as possible, than go to the next lower unit ...

Comment: That i do understand, but how to do it with javacode i dont understand.

Answer (score 0):

Cast product to `double` value, i.e.: `int svar1 = (int)(dollar * valuta);`, but then you lose fraction part. Better approach is to declare `svar1` as `double`: `double svar1 = dollar * valuta`. Then, when you open message dialog, you need to properly construct message string. So, if you want to concatenate different factors into one string, you need to use `+` operator (and you have to make sure, that at least one of those factors is actually a string). So you need:

> `showMessageDialog(null, dollar + " * " + valuta + " = " + svar1 + "\n");`

But if you want to have more control over format, you should consider using `format` method of `String` class (since 1.5; [see javadoc for String.format explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)). Eventually you can use this:

> `showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%0.2f * %0.2f = %0.2f\n", dollar, valuta, svar1));`

---

Well, you actually ask for something else now. Okay, see this (with an example of use):

```
private static final int[] PAYMENT_UNITS = {
    1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1
};

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    printCashOut(split(2004307));
}

private static final void printCashOut(final int[] cacheOut) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < PAYMENT_UNITS.length; i++) {
        final int p = cacheOut[i] * PAYMENT_UNITS[i];
        System.out.printf("%4d x %4d = %8d\n",
                cacheOut[i],
                PAYMENT_UNITS[i],
                p
            );
        total += p;
    }
    System.out.printf("       TOTAL: %8d\n", total);
}

private static final int[] split(final int amount) {
    if (amount < 0) {
        return null;
    }
    final int[] cashOut = new int[PAYMENT_UNITS.length];
    int rest = amount;
    for (int i = 0; i < PAYMENT_UNITS.length; i++) {
        cashOut[i] = rest / PAYMENT_UNITS[i];
        rest -= cashOut[i] * PAYMENT_UNITS[i];
    }
    return cashOut;
}
```

Comment: The program should calculate and show how this amount most effectively can be cashed out i all norwegian paying units. 1000kr, 500kr,200kr,100kr,50kr,20kr,10kr,5kr,1kr. And i dont have noe idea how i can do this:( Everything else does work.